Struggling to understand vector calculus
I was working through an energy calculation for the Fokker-Planck equation:
$$
\partial_t \rho + \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{v}\rho) = 0
$$where
$$
\mathbf{v} = -(\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla\rho + \nabla V).
$$
At equilibrium, the density $\rho(\mathbf{x},\,t)$ no longer changes with time, $\rho(\mathbf{x},\,t) = \rho_{\inf}$.
We get that
$$
\rho_{inf} (\mathbf{x},\,t) = Ce^{-V(\mathbf{x})}
$$
Let $\phi : [0, inf) \rightarrow [0,inf)$ be a smooth function such that $\phi(1) = \phi’(1) = 0.$
$$
E(\rho) = \int_{\Omega}\phi(\frac{\rho}{\rho_{inf}})\rho_{inf} dx.
$$
In the solution, I was given the following line:
$$
\frac{dE}{dt} = \int_{\Omega} \phi’(\frac{\rho}{\rho_{inf}})\partial_t\rho dx = -\int_{\Omega}\nabla\phi’(\frac{\rho}{\rho_{inf}}) \cdot (\nabla \rho + \rho\nabla V) dx
$$
I am not sure how they arrive at the last equality. When I asked my professor, he said it was integration by parts/Green’s identity.
Cheers.

Is the difficulty in understanding the IBP step?

Where is the "last inequality"?

Your function $\phi : [0, inf) \rightarrow [0,inf)$ is also dependent on $\mathbf{x}$? Note that $\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{v}\rho)=\nabla\rho\cdot\mathbf{v}+\rho\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}$ and $\int_{\Omega} \phi’(\frac{\rho}{\rho_{inf}})\partial_t\rho d\mathbf{x}=-\phi'\rho\mathbf{v}|0^1+\int{\Omega}\rho\mathbf{v}\nabla\phi 'd\mathbf{x}=\int_{\Omega}\nabla(\frac{\rho}{\rho_{inf}}) \cdot (\nabla \rho + \rho\nabla V)d\mathbf{x}$

Does $\nabla(\rho/\rho_\inf) $refers to $\nabla \phi'(\rho/\rho_\inf) $ ? Also there seems to be a sign issue ?

@SeanRoberson yes

@MathArt apologies I meant equality. Have made the edit now.

@Steph yes I am referring to $\nabla \phi ‘(\frac{\rho}{\rho_{inf}})$

why not use $\mathrm{div}(f\mathbf{a}) = f\mathrm{div}(\mathbf{a}) + \nabla f : \mathbf{a} $

@Steph when doing that we get $f\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{a}) = ( \nabla f) \mathbf{a }- \nabla \cdot (f \mathbf{a})$. Where does the $\nabla \cdot (f \mathbf{a})$ term go?

I think you swap terms on the right hand side. This is a relevant question. Maybe if you apply the divergence theorem, you will find the reason why.
